# Truthiness test not performing as expected

Tags: python, truthiness

I have a simple function that tests an item in a tuple to see if it is truthy or not. For some reason all tests come back True (`...if connection:...`), even though the value being tested is either a 1 (assumed True) or 0 (assumed false).

I tested to see if 1 == True (output: True), 1 == False (False), connection is True (False) just to try to understand what is going on.

User input: `players = [('a', 1), ('b', 0)]`

Function:

```
def validplayers(players):
    for player, connection in players:
        if connection:
            player
        print player, connection, 1 == True, 1 == False, connection is True
```

Output:

```
a 1 True False False
b 0 True False False
```

The `connection` var is passing a 1 or 0 which `type(connection)` defines as an int.

Comment: You are not *doing* anything in the `if` statement. You just reference `player`, but nothing else. That expression achieves nothing.

Comment: I'm a student learning python. Shouldn't the function show only those players who have a 1 (True) connection?

Comment: Why should it? The `print` statement is not part of the `if` test. It is **always** executed.

Comment: If you want that to happen, the `print` is positioned at the wrong indentation.

Comment: Are questions from students learning the language not accepted? Not sure why or what downvoting a question means. Is it a stupid question or does this mean that its too easy for stack overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is looking at `connection is True`. This is *always going to be `False`*. `is` [tests for *identity*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not), two expressions resulting in a reference to the *same object in memory*.

If you want to print the truth value of an object, use the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool):

```
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

That `1 == True` works at all is because in Python, the `bool` type is a subclass of `int`:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

The integer value of `True` is 1, and `False` has an integer value of `0`. Testing for equality won't work for other integer values:

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 2 == True
False
>>> bool(2)
True
```

Note that your `if` test is otherwise meaningless; the only thing that is executed or not is the line `player`, which is a no-op expression that just returns the reference to `player`, but since there is nothing else there the reference is unused.

If you wanted the `print` statement to be executed only when `if` is true, you need to indent it to be further to the right from `if` and make it part of the nested block:

```
def validplayers(players):
    for player, connection in players:
        if connection:
            print player, connection, bool(connection)
```

This then only prints something for player `a`:

```
>>> def validplayers(players):
...     for player, connection in players:
...         if connection:
...             print player, connection, bool(connection)
...
>>> validplayers([('a', 1), ('b', 0)])
a 1 True
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! This solved the problem. I want to eventually use this function in my module to pass valid players into another function to form 'teams'. I might have more silly questions coming up.